# How to generate Dynamic button in a table row and open new page on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

i actually having a requirement of generating dynamic table from services `url` and after that generating dynamic table.This is i worked it out but what i want  is

1. How to generate a dynamic button on each table row with click event.
2. After generating the button how we can assign click events to the button i mean suppose in a table there are four columns like **date,id number,name,location**  and on the clicking on the each column or related to that cell it has to redirect to a new page.

or

3. if a table row is clicked and there are 4 columns are there like  **date,id number,name,location**  the click event has will take date as a parameter and click event function and then it have to proceed to the next page/redirect

   ```
   $('#btn_Day').click(function () { 

   var ex = document.getElementById("dpp_info");
   var clOptions = ex.options[ex.selectedIndex].value;
   var clOptions1 = ex.options[ex.selectedIndex].text;

   var dt = todaydate;
   var dt1 = todaydate;

   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx,
       data: frmDate_=" + dt + "&toDate_=" + dt1 + "",

       success: function (resp) {

           var Location = resp;

           var tr;        

           for (var i = 0; i < Location.length; i++) {

               tr = tr + "<tr>";
                tr = tr + "<td  style='height:20px' align='left'>" + Location[i].Name + "</td>";
               tr = tr + "<td  style='height:20px' align='left'>" +  Location[i].Date + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "<td style='height:20px' align='left'>" + Location[i].IdNum + "</td>";


               tr = tr + "</tr>";

           };

           document.getElementById('Wise').innerHTML = "<table class='r'>" + "<tr><thead ><th  style='height:20px'>Location</th>"
           + "<th  style='height:20px'>Date</th>" + "<th  style='height:20px'>Id Num</th>" + "</tr></thead>"
           + tr +
           "<tr></tr>" +
           "</table>";
           document.getElementById('Wise').childNodes[0].nodeValue = null;

       },
       error: function (e) {

           window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Please Enable your Internet connection");

       }
   });
   });
   ```

   [image]

now  in the image if u see there are four columns suppose if i click on the idnumb and there records related to that particular number has to be displayed in separate page

Looking For Help!

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do but it sounds like you're wanting to add handler date, id number, name and location. Could you add a class to the column/row and any other attributes you need such as data-name='number'. Once you have added this to the dom you could then add handlers for that class?

Comment: @JamesDale please check the question

Comment: So if I clicked on 22 it would show me other records where the IdNum is 22?

Comment: Check this out to see if it helps https://jsfiddle.net/p2fpbkuo/ results will be logged in console

Comment: @JamesDale  ok how can i generate dynamic button instead of clicking on the whole row  we can choose clicking on the button and after clicking on the button it can redirect to the new page

Comment: You would just add a button in when building your template. Then add a handler to that button. Do you actually want to navigate to a new page? Or display the results?

Comment: @JamesDale after click it has to navigate to the new page in the any way i will display result by using onclick function which  i am going to create  using the dynamically created table and could u tell me how can i create a dynamic buttons in my loop on each row how can i create a button and an onclick event for that ?

Comment: So you would need to add a button to the row and maybe another class so you could create an handler. I added a Url property to the object array. When clicked you could just do a window.open(url).  have updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p2fpbkuo/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149893/discussion-between-madpop-and-james-dale).

Comment: @JamesDale could you please check this https://jsfiddle.net/madpop143/v13dhork/ and here i am  assigning  click functionality but it is not working

Comment: Do you need to do this: 
$('.btnAction').on('click', function(e) {
    
})

Comment: @JamesDale it is not working

Comment: Hey, I have updated the jsfiddle. You needed to add the handlers once you added the elements to the dom https://jsfiddle.net/v13dhork/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more discussion on this the key was to just use the handler and pass any values using attributes. You can see the fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/p2fpbkuo/3/

```
$('.button-click').off();
$('.button-click').on('click', function () {
    // navigate to new page
 // console.log('button click')

 // what you could do here is get the serialnumber which is an attribute on the button 
 var id = $(this).attr('data-id') // as long as this is unique this should always work

 var filteredResults = results.filter(function (result) {
  if (result.SerialNumber.toString() === id.toString()) {
    return result;
  }
});

var selectedRowValues = filteredResults[0];

// this will contain all the values for that row
console.log(selectedRowValues)

 // var dataValue = $(this).attr('data-url'); // dont't need this any more
 window.open(selectedRowValues.Url)
});
```